# With Braintree's Hosted Fields integration, does tokenization trigger a card verification? If so, how can I prevent verification attacks?

Tags: braintree

We have a donation form that is integrated with Braintree using Hosted Fields (the sensitive fields are iframes). We are getting a huge number of failed card verifications and are trying to figure out how to stop them.

When I call the tokenize() function, does that trigger a card verification? If so, how can I prevent verification attacks on the form?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to Braintree support, tokenization does not trigger a card verification.